# Make image full width

Tags: html, css, image, containers

I am attempting to fit an image into my header element. When I run Live Server, the image does not fill entire width of container.

**Edit**
*the dimensions of the image is 899.875X600*

Here is my **CSS** and **HTML** code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

header {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: auto;
    height: 600px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <img id='backgroundImg' src="image.jpg" alt="">
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have `position: absolute;` on the body?

Comment: @j08691, I want to make the body fit the entire screen

Comment: what about the ratios heigth-width , are they the same ?

Comment: @MisterJojo, I just edited the dimensions in, 899.875 by 600px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you not have position absolute on your body. Use `100vh` unit for that. It also depends on how you want to image to behave inside the header, it isn't that clear in your question. Is this what you want?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 1rem;
}

img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img id='backgroundImg' src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="image">
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
   
    color: white;    
    height: calc(100vh - 4px);  
    border:solid 2px red;
    z-index:5;
}

header {    
  
  height:30vh;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/100');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        
    </header>
</body>
```